# Linux redirection and piping

Tags: linux, redirection, pipe

I am working on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I a directory, I have only 2 files

```
a1.txt a2.txt
```

when I run the `ls a* z* 2> /dev/null | cat` I got the result , that is OK. I mean that error was not shown.

But 1- when I run the `ls a* z* 2> /dev/null |& cat` I expect that the errors be discarded because of error redirection to null device. and 2- when I run the `ls a* z* 1> /dev/null |& cat` no output was displayed. But I expect that the errors be displayed!

Thank you

Comment: `|&` is a shorthand for `2>&1 |` so you are sending stderr to stdout and stdout is already going to /dev/null. Do you really want `ls a* z* 2>&1 >/dev/null`, e.g. send stderr to the current stdout and then redirect stdout to /dev/null without touching other file descriptors?

Comment: And, in case this is nearly the actual code you're using, [don't parse the output of ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).